# What are the traditional rules for at photo mat measurements?

Tags: presentation, frames

I learned about this in primary school; but that is some years ago so I do not recall exactly how it was. I understand there is no *correct way* to do this – but anyhow we learned the "*correct way*". :)

I remember something in the direction of:

> Having a picture of `X × Y` the mat should be `some formula` high, and `some formula` wide (if creating frame as well as mat). We also learned, as I recall, that the mat opening should be a tiny bit above, or below, centre; one border should be slightly thicker. This to drag the eyes downward, or to weight the picture down.

What is the *standard* way to measure this? I understand there is no *correct way* to do this — but as we learned some concrete numbers to work with — and they gave good results and would think there is some basic guidelines for this.

My most important question is which border should be thicker – and by how much.

I got really confused finding [this post on eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_5064110_size-picture-frame-mat.html) (see step 5), where they state the **width** should be greater. I definitely remember it was either top or bottom.

Comment: Related (about digital borders): [Is there any guideline for photo frame width?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25086/is-there-any-guideline-for-photo-frame-width)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have learned it, the bottom border should be thicker than the other borders.

As with almost any rule of design or layout, this is not a strict rule to follow, just a guideline for what's balanced. If you want a different effect than a neutral, balanced frame, you can cut the mat any way you like.

Comment: Thank you for your reply; I came to the same conclusion as you have learned by testing some layouts. I also added a guide for one method that I guess is pretty "standard/classic".

Answer (score 3):

Looking around, this is one of the more frequent methods I've found; same applies for both portrait and landscape: (Made a little guide as it is easier to read (picture from tumblr.com))

[image: traditional mat guide]

Giving us a result like this:

[image: mat result]

By calculating one could do – my geometry is a bit rusty so there is perhaps an easier way; but by taking advantage of angle by `tan` of opposite and adjacent side to the right triangle we get something like:

Having

```
a: mat width
b: mat height
c: image width
d: image height
```

We get

```
S: sides
T: top
B: bottom
```

By

```
S = (a - c) / 2

    a(b - d) + c(b - d)
T = -------------------
           4a

B = b - d - T
```

Alternatively `B` by:

```
     (3a - c)(b - d)
B = ------------------
            4a
```

---

Example

```
a = 21, b = 30, c = 17, d = 24

S = (21 - 17) / 2 = 2


b - d = 30 - 24 = 6

T = (21 * 6 + 17 * 6) / (4 * 21) = 2.71

B = 30 - 24 - 2.71 = 3.29
```

Comment: This photo is small enough that it's probably fair use, but it'd be _better_ to choose something that's either yours or already licensed CC-BY-SA (the Creative Commons license used on this site).

Comment: @mattdm; OK. Thank you for that notice. I'll remember that.